# Reading many elements - how to avoid if ( ...!= null) chaos? (nesting)

Tags: c#, xml

I'm reading an xml file using Microsoft Linq in a C# project. I access data from the xml-document like this:

```
document.Root.Element("myElement").Attribute("myAttribute").Value
```

I get warnings that this could result in a `NullReferenceException`. I have to check for `null`) (for every element and attribute I want to read).

However, I don't want to have many nested if checks, like this:

```
 if (... != null) {
    if (... != null) {
       if (... != null) {
          if (... != null) {
             if (... != null) {
                 ...
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

This gets ugly pretty fast. Is there a better way in `C#`? In `Swift`, there is something called [guard statement](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/), which would be ideal in this case. It also allows to "force unwrap" these things, which tells the compiler that this can't ever be null. Is there an equivalent in C#?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean like the [null-conditional operator `.?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)?

Comment: Is `XPath` an option for you?

Comment: The null propagation mentioned above would be viable syntax.  `a?.b?.c?.d = value;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you hear about the [null-conditional (or null-propagation) operator `?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)?
You could write the statement like that:

```
var v = document.Root?.Element("myElement")?.Attribute("myAttribute")?.Value;
```

So if `Root` is `null` or `Element("myElement")` returns `null` or `Attribute("myAttribute")` returns `null`, the result will be `null`.

Comment: Oh damn, in `swift` this means the literal opposite, that's why I didn't even consider it. I'll accept this once I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this chain I usually use this pattern:

```
if(... == null)
    break; // or continue; // or return; // depends on the context
if(... == null)
    break; // or continue; // or return; // depends on the context
...
```

This will break this chain into a sequence of null checks

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
if( ... !=null && ...!=null && ...!=null...)
```

or try catch
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: will work but not a good approach, note that  i didn't downvoted